# web speech listener

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho a seguinte programação. Ela escreve nos input o text4 e o text5 pelo button correspondente.

Porem queria fazer automatico, ou seja, quando inicio input, via text4, a propria função listen4() abrisse o MIC5 como o button faz.Afinal nesta função eu chamo a função listen5(). Mas isto não acontece.
Preciso de ajuda para isto.

```
<button class="btn" onclick="listen4()">MIC
4:</button>
<input id="text4">
..............................
<button class="btn" onclick="listen5()">MIC
5:</button>
<input id="text5">
........................
function listen4() {
listener.listen("pt", function(text4) {
document.getElementById("text4").value = text4 ; nota4 = document.getElementById("text4").value; speaker.speak("pt", nota4);listen5();})}
..................................................

function listen5() {
listener.listen("pt", function(text4) {
document.getElementById("text5").value = text5 ; nota5 = document.getElementById("text5").value; speaker.speak("pt", nota5); })}
..................................................
```

Comment: Abra o console do browser e veja se deu algum erro.

Comment: não dá erro. O que acontece é que a função listen5 só é executada quando clico no button mic5. Eu queria que o button mic4 depois de executar a função listen4, executasse também a listen5. Mas ela para no começo do listener.listen da função listen5. Sei disso, pois coloquei um alert ali.

Comment: Se o script para, é porque deu um erro. Você chegou a olhar o console e não tinha nada? O alert não garante que não tenha dado nenhum erro.

Comment: Não aparece nada não. Li em algum lugar, que para o listener.listen funcionar, sem o button, precisa monitorar o microfone para ver se tem alguma alteração. Deve existir algum método  para monitorar o microfone.Porem veja, que quando clico no button, funciona, só não funciona, quando invoco a função, sem clicar no button.